# Getting no output from script I wrote (changed from the given script) to solve a picoCTF challenge

Tags: python

I am solving a challenge from picoCTF - PW Crack 5 ([PW Crack 5](https://play.picoctf.org/events/69/challenges/challenge/249?page=2))

I was given a dictionary containing the possible solutions (around 65000) and I thought that the best way is to loop through the dictionary and pass each line through the function that decodes the hash. However, the code yields no output.

The given script from the challenge:

```
import hashlib

### THIS FUNCTION WILL NOT HELP YOU FIND THE FLAG --LT ########################
def str_xor(secret, key):
    #extend key to secret length
    new_key = key
    i = 0
    while len(new_key) < len(secret):
        new_key = new_key + key[i]
        i = (i + 1) % len(key)        
    return "".join([chr(ord(secret_c) ^ ord(new_key_c)) for (secret_c,new_key_c) in zip(secret,new_key)])
###############################################################################

flag_enc = open('level5.flag.txt.enc', 'rb').read()
correct_pw_hash = open('level5.hash.bin', 'rb').read()


def hash_pw(pw_str):
    pw_bytes = bytearray()
    pw_bytes.extend(pw_str.encode())
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(pw_bytes)
    return m.digest()


def level_5_pw_check():
    user_pw = input("Please enter correct password for flag: ")
    user_pw_hash = hash_pw(user_pw)
    
    if( user_pw_hash == correct_pw_hash ):
        print("Welcome back... your flag, user:")
        decryption = str_xor(flag_enc.decode(), user_pw)
        print(decryption)
        return
    print("That password is incorrect")


level_5_pw_check()
```

The  script  after  I  modified  it:

```
import hashlib

### THIS FUNCTION WILL NOT HELP YOU FIND THE FLAG --LT ########################
def str_xor(secret, key):
    #extend key to secret length
    new_key = key
    i = 0
    while len(new_key) < len(secret):
        new_key = new_key + key[i]
        i = (i + 1) % len(key)
    return "".join([chr(ord(secret_c) ^ ord(new_key_c)) for (secret_c,new_key_c) in zip(secret,new_key)])
###############################################################################

flag_enc = open('level5.flag.txt.enc', 'rb').read()
correct_pw_hash = open('level5.hash.bin', 'rb').read()


def hash_pw(pw_str):
    pw_bytes = bytearray()
    pw_bytes.extend(repr(pw_str).encode())
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(pw_bytes)
    return m.digest()


def level_5_pw_check():
    user_pw = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
    for i in user_pw:
      user = i.strip()
      user_pw_hash = hash_pw( user)

      if( user_pw_hash == correct_pw_hash ):
          print("Welcome back... your flag, user:")
          decryption = str_xor(repr(flag_enc.decode()), user)
          print(decryption)
          break

level_5_pw_check()
```

I am sure that it may be a noob-ish mistake since I am still new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot the else block that tells you your attempt failed.
You should also print the answer inside the if block so you know which value is the correct one. (Print the user variable as well)